# Memory Management with ARC, strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I declared a Global Object:

```
YViewController * yViewController
```

When in App Launch I am calling:

```
[self methodOne];
```

The method does this:

```
-(void)methodOne
{
 yViewController = [[YViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YViewController" bundle:nil];
 self.window.rootViewController=yViewController;
}
```

When a button clicked in YViewController I am calling:

```
[self methodTwo];
```

The method does this:

```
-(void)methodTwo
{
  XViewController * xViewController = [[XViewController alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
  self.window.rootViewController=xViewController;
}
```

When a back button tapped on `XViewController` I am calling `[self methodOne];` which navigates back to the `YViewController`.

The issue is, while I am using ARC, I could not flush/release the `xViewController` object. Also when checking on instruments,
the memory of `XViewController` keep on increasing as I tap back and forth between `XViewController` and `YViewController`.

How can I manage memory in this type of situations with ARC?

Comment: Why don't you use Navigation Controller for Navigation?

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, The XViewController actually from a third party library and its already a navigation controller. thats the reason.

Comment: you Should try Navigation controller, its a couple of line code to make it work. plus since u mentioned its a Third Party tool then may be the Memory management in that XViewController is poor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source of XViewController is open, I would have tweaked it to go with navigation. Any ways ..

Okay so, basically you are creating a new object of ViewController every time, and that is what is resulting in the pile of the memory.

You should have 'XViewController * xViewController' and 'YViewController * yViewController' as class variables and your methods should be some thing like this eg.

Look if the object exists, and if it does, don't allocate it again.

```
-(void)methodTwo
{
 if(xViewController == nil)
 {
   xViewController = [[XViewController alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
 }
  self.window.rootViewController=xViewController;

}
```